# How to make a dropdown overlaps a div that has width and overflow-x hidden?

Tags: html, css

Here is my issue:

I have a `div` with some specific width, inside that `div` i have a dropdown and some other elements that shows as popups or dropdowns, if i just set the `overflow` properties to default it works fine.

But i need it to scroll and when i set the `overflow: scroll` my `dropdown` just is cutted like the snipped down below, there is some way that i can show the dropdown outside the square (in my snipped) keeping the scroll?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown dropright">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
      data-toggle="dropdown">Click me</button>
      
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a result of the `overflow` alongside `position: relative` on the dropdown parent.

Just setting the `<div class="dropdown dropright">` to `position: static;` solves the issue:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdown.dropright {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown dropright">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
      data-toggle="dropdown">Click me</button>
      
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that this has the downside that you can no longer use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` on absolute positioned children when these positions are meant to relate to the parent.

Instead (as Bootstrap does) you use `transform: translate(...)` for the positioning of absolute children.